# Настройка веб сервера без домена

Tags: apache, веб-сервер, администрирование

Нужно настроить апач чтоб он обрабатывал сайт по адресу каталога а не домена
те вариант  [http://моисайт.ру/админка](http://xn--80apejktj.xn--p1ag/%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0) - мне не нужен

Нужно сделать так
[http://192.168.22.1/админка](http://192.168.22.1/%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0)
[http://192.168.22.1/чат](http://192.168.22.1/%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82)
[http://192.168.22.1/статистика](http://192.168.22.1/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)
и тд.

Каждый раздел в url это полноценный ОТДЕЛЬНЫЙ сайт с отдельным каталогом

Апач 2.4   также рассмотрю варианты на nginx

Comment: Апач не занимается доменными именами. Ничего делать не надо. Запустите сервер и задайте в браузере адрес "192.168.22.1" будет вам сайт "Апач работает!"

Comment: это у меня есть. Мне надо чтоб как у денвера работало,  открыл адрес там заглушка на главной, дописал в адресе путь /tools/phpmyadmin и опа админка  ,  только мне их  там 3 разных  надо

Comment: Вы сначала установите apache и потом, если не получается, спрашивайте. Вы не выложили информацию о своей операционной системе сервера. Как отвечать?

Comment: centos 7,  тут апач называется httpd и он стоит, и прописан в автозапуск и стартовую даже показывает.

Comment: Вроде-бы по-русски всё написано : [Centos Apache](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-centos-7-ru)

Comment: не знаю как еще сформулировать вопрос..  как работает веб сервер и как настроить сайт я знаю.,  и эту инструкцию и много других я уже прочитал. Мне не нужен example.com мне нужно сделать так example.com\site1  example.com\site2   и тд ,  каждый сайт это отдельная папка со своим отдельным индексом и тд

Comment: добавьте в начальную страницу директории, и по ним допишите в каждую `index.php` (*`index.html`*). Одного сайта хватит.

Comment: те просто ссылки на индексы в подкаталогах ?  это конечно вариант но хотелось бы как в денвере ..   http:\\ localhost\tools\phpmyadmin

Comment: А в `http://localhost/index.html` ссылки на под-сайты написать не пробовали?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39239276/how-to-enable-a-directory-listing-in-apache-web-server